# Retrieve SharedPreferences in retrofit2 interface

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm trying to add programmatically an authorization header to my api calls with retrofit and rxjava2 so i added an okhttp3 interceptor to it. This is my full code:

```
public interface APIService {

    class ServiceInterceptor implements Interceptor{


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            if (request.header("No-Authentication") == null){
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = ???.getSharedPreferences(USER, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); <---
                request = request.newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "JWT " + sharedPref.getString("auth_token", null))
                        .build();
            }
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    }


    OkHttpClient apiClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .addInterceptor(new ServiceInterceptor())
            .build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.8:8000/api/v1/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(apiClient)
            .build();

    @GET("rest-auth/user/")
    Single<Response<User>> getUserDetails();

    @POST("rest-auth/login/")
    @Headers("No-Authorization: true")
    Single<Response<AuthUserResponse>> loginUser(@Body LoginRequest body);

    @POST("rest-auth/registration/")
    @Headers("No-Authorization: true")
    Single<Response<AuthUserResponse>> signupUser(@Body SignupRequest body);

}
```

The problem is that i can't retrieve the auth_token from sharedPreferences because i don't know how to pass the context to it. Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: how about adding constructor in `ServiceInterceptor` class?

Comment: Already tried it but then i have to pass `context` in `.addInterceptor(new ServiceInterceptor())`

Comment: and what about adding one more method parameter in `public okhttp3.Response intercept (@NonNull Chain chain,Context mContext)` ?

Comment: I can't pass context there, method does not override from its superclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a constructor for your `ServiceInterceptor` class, passing the `auth_token` as a param, something like

```
 private String authToken;

 public ServiceInterceptor(String authToken) {
     this.authToken = authToken;
 }
```

That way you handle the context and SharedPreferences outside your interceptor class, it shouldn't know about android stuff anyway.

Then on your `intercept` method you can get the authToken.

Comment: And how can i call SharedPreferences in the interface?

Comment: You shoudn't. The interface is really only for the API methods. 
Create a class for the HttpClient and Retrofit creation, and keep both outside of the interface.

Comment: So in total you should have 3 classes. 
Interceptor class,
Retrofit instance class,
API interface class.